# Delete a branch in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I delete a branch in TortoiseSVN?

1. Can I simply delete the working copy of the branch and the folder in the repository?
2. Should the local working copy of the branch first be deleted, or the branch folder through the `Repository Browser` be removed?

Answer (score 97):

Right click on any folder, select "Repo-browser" and find your branch on the left panel. From there, you can issue a "Delete" command directly on the repository:

[image: Repository browser screenshot]

As far as I know, you cannot issue a delete command on the top folder* of the working copy, probably because that would effectively destroy the working copy.

(*) You can of course remove the branch from the working copy if it's an *inner* folder, i.e., you check out e.g. `https://svn.example.com/repo/project/branches` instead of `https://svn.example.com/repo/project/branches/feature-blah`.

Comment: With tsvn 1.11, you can delete the top folder of the working copy. Of course, the working copy isn't a real working copy after that, but can be used to check for changes...

Comment: @Wolf What are the exact steps? I can't figure out myself.

Comment: right click on working copy top directory (i.e. the folder that contains the `.svn` folder); click on *TortoiseSVN -> Repo-browser*; right click on the corresponding folder on the left side of the window (should be pre-selected); click on *Delete...*; write log message and hit [OK]. After that, the working copy still exists, so you can: right click on it; click on *TortoiseSVN -> Check for modifications*. What doesn't work is update to HEAD, but you may as well update to a revision after creation and before deletion of that branch. So the working copy is actually intact, but limited.

Comment: @Wolf Not sure if I'm missing something. Is that different to what I describe in my answer? You're describing a deletion right on the repository, not in the working copy :-?

Comment: It's just that your secondary (*you cannot issue a delete command on the top folder of the working copy*) wasn't true (any more) in my case. Maybe this is due to the TSVN development after you answered.

Comment: @Wolf Repository browser does not operate on the working copy. If just populates the URL from the working copy one. The proof is that after deletion you don't need to commit and changes are instantly available for other clients.

Comment: Well, I know that. I just found this part of your answer confusing: "you cannot issue a delete command on the top folder of the working copy" -- what did you actually mean by that? I think the OP asked for an advice how (and when) to get rid of the working copy related to the corresponding branch.

Answer (score 12):

The SVN book ("Version Control with Subversion") explains how to [delete and restore branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s07.html#svn-ch-4-sect-7.2).

Although it suggests remote deletion like

```
$ svn delete http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch \
  -m "Removing obsolete branch of calc project."
```

you could also do it locally (with the TortoiseSVN > Delete command).

As mentioned in the book, you can always restore branches, so you won't get any unexpected consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where could I send such a command in tortoise?

Comment: Right-click on the branch directory, TortoiseSVN, Delete

Comment: TortoiseSVN is built with the subversion library, so it doesn't contain the necessary binaries (like svn.exe). You need to download them before you can execute textual commands (http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows). But that's not recommended - TortoiseSVN is a GUI, why would you want to use the command line?

Comment: As of 2016, the TortoiseSVN package has been including command line binaries for a while, though they're an optional component during install.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I delete a branch in TortoiseSVN?

There's more than one way to do this, but after years of experience with Tortoise I have found deleting via the Repository Browser to be the least troublesome way.

Right click on the working copy and open the Repo-browser:

[image]

The browser looks like this:

[image]

Right click on the item and choose to delete it. You'll then be asked for a commit summary. Enter your rationale and click OK.

> Can I simply delete the working copy of the branch and the folder in
>   the repository?

If you have the branch checked out on its own, i.e. just that branch with its own `.svn` folder then technically there is no need to delete the working copy. The order of operation doesn't matter in this scenario.

> Should the local working copy of the branch first be deleted, or the
>   branch folder through the repository browser be removed?

If the item you are deleting is checked out as part of a bigger tree - for example, you have the entire `/branches` folder checked out in one place - I recommend deleting via the Repo-browser and then svn updating the working copy to pick up the deletion.